# Event guest list with user groups getting status by guest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to pull the list of guests for a calendar event and figure out each of the guests status (YES, NO, MAYBE) but ran into a problem with a user group.  It just gives me the group name and a status of INVITED, but I need each guest in the user group and their invite status.   Is this possible?

```
var calendarName="calendar name";
var calDate=new Date("04/02/2013");

function testCalendarEvents(){
var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName);  
var events = calendars[0].getEventsForDay(calDate); 

for(var c=0; c<events.length; c++){
Logger.log("Event "+c+": "+events[c].getTitle());

var guestList=events[c].getGuestList();    
for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++){
  Logger.log("Guest "+d+": "+guestList[d].getEmail()+", Status: "+guestList[d].getGuestStatus());      
}        
}  
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Your code shows the status for each guest.  Are you in fact adding a Contacts group through the Gcal Ui?

Comment: Expanding on @BryanP's comment - a group created in gmail will expand to all members when added through the GCal UI. So, could you explain what your "User Group" is?

Comment: Thanks for the response @BryanP I should have clarified the User Group.  In this instance the User Group is a domain User Group, not one I created.  Would I need admin rights to access that User Group (which I don't have at the moment) or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for DomainGroups presently, as there is no apps-script API support for drilling in to the status of group members. According to the documentation, you should be able to view those users and their status through the Calendar UI, assuming that you have appropriate permissions to view group members.

From the [Enterprise Calendar FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/users/en/learning_center/faqs_calendar.html):

> **Can I invite a mailing list from our corporate directory to a meeting?**
>
> Yes, you can invite any mailing list (group) in our corporate
>   directory to a meeting. Each member of the group will receive an email
>   invitation. Note, however, that the email invitation won't show all
>   the members of the group. Also, the group members will appear in the
>   invitation on each attendee's calendar only if you have permission to
>   view the group's member list.

If you are a Domain Administrator, you can use the [GroupsManager](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/groups-manager) service to retrieve the memberslist of a group. Unfortunately, within the context of a Calendar Event, that's about the only useful thing you can do. You cannot get the invitation status of individual users. I've modified your script to retrieve the member list:

```
function testCalendarEvents(){
  var calendarName="david_bingham@mitel.com";
  var calDate=new Date("04/01/2013");
  var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName);  
  var events = calendars[0].getEventsForDay(calDate); 

  try {
    var domainAdmin = false;          // assume we aren't an admin in a domain
    GroupsManager.getGroup("test");
    domainAdmin = true;               // we passed the test, so we ARE
  }
  catch (error) {
    // We didn't pass the test... why not?
    // Get "Service error: : Invalid request URI" if outside of an enterprise account
    // Get "You do not have permission to perform that action." if not admin.
    Logger.log("Not Domain Admin: "+error.message);
  }

  for(var c=0; c<events.length; c++){
    Logger.log("Event "+c+": "+events[c].getTitle());

    var guestList=events[c].getGuestList();    
    for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++){
      if (!domainAdmin) {
        Logger.log("Guest "+d+": "+guestList[d].getEmail()+", Status: "+guestList[d].getGuestStatus());
      }
      else {
        // Check if this guest is a group
        var group = GroupsManager.getGroup(guestList[d].getEmail());
        if (group) {
          // getAllMembers() returns an array of email addresses
          var groupMembers = group.getAllMembers();
          for (var e in groupMembers) {
            Logger.log("Guest "+d+"/"+e+": "+groupMembers[e]+
                       ", Status: "+"UNKNOWN(group "+guestList[d].getEmail()+")");
          }
        }
        else {
          Logger.log("Guest "+d+": "+guestList[d].getEmail()+", Status: "+guestList[d].getGuestStatus());
        }
      }
    }        
  }  
}
```