# Google App Script get number of participants who accepted invitation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I need to get number of participants who accepted invitation in Google Calendar, the problem is that beside of users there are also groups and as far as I see group I counted as 1 invitee. However, in Google Calendar itself number of people accepted invitation is visible on the event page.

Could you please advise how can I implement this?

That's what I've got so far:

```
function listEvents() {

  var today = new Date();
  var Calendar  =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var events = Calendar.getEvents(new Date(2016,12,1), new Date(today.getFullYear(),12,31));
  var eventarray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i<events.length; i++)
  {
    var line = new Array();
    line.push(events[i].getTitle());
    line.push(events[i].getStartTime());
    line.push(events[i].getEndTime());
    var guestList = events[i].getGuestList();
    var guests = new String();
    //var addit = 0;

    for (var b in guestList) {
        guests  = guests +''+guestList[b].getEmail()+'; ';
        //addit = addit + guestList[b].getAdditionalGuests();
      } 
    //line.push(addit);
    line.push(guests);

    eventarray.push(line);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, eventarray.length, eventarray[0].length).setValues(eventarray);
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't seem to get this attendee status info programmatically, only via the Calendar UI. The problem exists whether you use the [EventGuest.GuestList via CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) or [Event.attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) via the Calendar (Advanced service) or the pure Google Calendar API.

I also found a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694754/event-guest-list-with-user-groups-getting-status-by-guest) that may assist.

Comment: Thank you for help Peter, but unfortunately this doesn't work.
I already tried this one, and when there are 40 people invited as a group and 13 of them accepted all script is showing is that this group was invited and none of the accepts.

Comment: Thank you for explanation Peter. So, I guess in this case I have to look for workaround. Have a good day!